# How to load photo of PersonalContact returned by People API?

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph People API to search for people in my personal contacts and the organization directory.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$search=username
```

returning for example:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('123456789')/people",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$search=username&$skip=10",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "1234567890",
            ...
            "personType": {
                "class": "Person",
                "subclass": "OrganizationUser"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "0987654321",
            ...
            "personType": {
                "class": "Person",
                "subclass": "PersonalContact"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I request the photo of an internal Organization User ( `"subclass": "OrganizationUser"`), everything works.

When I'm request the some for a Personal Contact (`"subclass": "PersonalContact"`) photo service, `/me/contacts/{id}/photo/$value` returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidOperation",
        "message": "ConversationId isn't supported in the context of this operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1b55eca0-f83f-4e66-9006-b728373ad747",
            "date": "2019-01-04T01:06:27"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you get back from `/me/contacts/{id}`? And are you sure this contact has a photo in Outlook?

Comment: I'm getting the same error message, when calling /me/contacts/{id}! For my test, I selected a user which has photo.

Comment: When I compare the IDs of the people API and the contact API for the some personal contact, I can see that they have different values.  The value of the contact API is much longer. People API and user API using the some value as ID.

Comment: A Contact is an entirely different object from a User, they're sourced for separate systems. Users are held in AAD while Contacts are held by Exchange Online.  The People API constructs a Person object based on a search across multiple sources (i.e. both users and contacts). So a single Person isn't always the same as a single User _or_ Contact, they might be a combination of the two.

Comment: I have understood that the people API uses all kind of different interactions and directories. And it returns also implicit contacts, which are in no directory and only available based on conversations. Is there a way to get the contact ID based people API result or do I have create an additional search? Additional field with contact id or method to lookup contact id based conversation id?